# App cant access the network when deployed from a package only works if I run it from Visual Studio

Tags: microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

My app loads a page from a local IIS site.
If I run it from Visual Studio it works without issues.
If I build a Package and install it on the Surface it says
"unable to connect the requested page ... please try again later"
Firewall is off, enterprise and networks settings are on for the app.
Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys at the Microsoft Forum told me you can't create connection loops.
The follow up is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b172fb14-04c9-4a7d-8755-d22b5438b6c0/app-cant-access-the-network-when-deployed-from-a-package-only-works-if-i-run-it-from-visual-studio?forum=winappswithcsharp):

Answer (score 0):

Check you have added the **internetClient** capability in the package manifest.

Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx